UV Editor not showing texture but only purple even though texture is visible on object
So as in the title, the frame has a texture that is displayed on render mode, but when I enter the UV editor mode it show as in the picture. My shading is set to "texture" as in the second image I'e provided. Any ideas why?

the image selected in the UV Editor is the normal map, therefore the blue color

Go to Shader editor window and click on the Color Texture, or choose the desired texture from the UV Editor dropdown Menu in its Top Center.

It looks like you have set the Solid shading options to show Color > Texture and right now you have the normal map texture selected or it was the last texture selected. Read more about it in my answer here: Can not display a single mesh as solid.
